# Increment the page viewers count dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, increment

how to Increment the page viewers count dynamically. I am tried with localstorage but i'm uploaded to filezilla it's never works. how to solve this ?

```js
function anamtharaPageload() {
  let count = Number(localStorage.getItem('count')) || 0
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ` ${count}`
  // alert(`count ${count}`)
  localStorage.setItem('count', count + 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Local Storage Works System to the system and with local storage you cannot do it**, for this you need to store the count in the database and the add the count to current to show the number of users